# Difference between a "member variable" or "field" and a "global variable"

Tags: variables, global-variables

What is the difference between a member variable or field  and a global variable?Is the concept same ?

Comment: You can type the same on Google and see why google is best!

Comment: Do you think I didn't do that ? No answer couldn't satisfy me. Only that's why I asked this question here.

Comment: 1) You have not marked the language you are asking in reference to which makes your question broad. 2) When  you say you are not satisified, exactly which part you are confused with? 3) As of now your question is too broad and most likely be closed soon. You need to ask specific question about your dissatisfaction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A member variable is declared within the scope of a class.  Unless it’s static, there will be a different copy of the variable for every object of that class.

A global variable is declared outside the scope of any class and can be used from any function.  There’s only one copy of it in the program.

Note that mainstream object-oriented languages distinguish between a global variable (which is declared outside the scope of any class or function) and a static local variable or class member.  However, all the problems with global variables apply equally to mutable public data members that are accessible from anywhere in the program.  For most purposes, you can think of these as the same thing.

#### Example Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

const int global_var = 1;   // The definition of the global variable.

struct example_t {
  public:

  static int static_member_var; // A static member variable.
  const static int const_static_member_var; // These are just declarations.

  int member_var;                   // A non-static member variable.
  // Every object of this type will have its own member_var, while all
  // objects of this type will share their static members.
};

int example_t::static_member_var = 0;
const int example_t::const_static_member_var = global_var;
// We can use global_var here.  Both of these exist only once in the
// program, and must have one definition.  Outside the scope where we
// declared these, we must give their scope to refer to them.

int main(void)
{
  example_t a, b;   // Two different example_t structs.

  a.member_var = 2;
  b.member_var = 3; // These are different.

  a.static_member_var = 5;
  // This is another way to refer to it.  Because b has the same variable, it
  // changes it for both.

  // We can use global_var from main(), too.
  cout << "global_var is " << global_var
       << ", example_t::const_static_member_var is " << example_t::const_static_member_var
       << ", b.static_member_var is " << b.static_member_var
       << ", a.member_var is " << a.member_var
       << " and b.member_var is " << b.member_var
       << "."  << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But an example will be appreciable

Comment: You didn’t tag this with any language, so I’ll use C++.

Comment: Well, it’s written now.  Java’s rules are slightly different, but it’s based on C++, so very similar.  Its globals are more like the “static member variables” in my example.

Comment: Thanks for the Nice Example

Comment: This is not a good definition for global variables. As global variables *can* be declared inside the scope of a class. A better definition for global variables is that global variables are variables declared outside of a function scopes.

Comment: @M.Ed In mainstream languages, a static variable defined within the scope of a class, even if it is accessible from anywhere in the program is still considered a class member. A global variable is defined outside of any class or function scope. However, a static mutable variable accessible from any code does have all the same problems of global variables and is effectively the same thing.

Comment: @Davislor Yeah it might be language dependant, for example Kotlin's documentation refers to global variables as variables outside function scope (i.e. they could be outside or inside class scope).

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are any variables defined outside functions scope, they can be accessed anywhere in the program if they were defined outside of class scope, or they can only be accessed inside a class if they were defined inside the class's scope.

Local variables are any variables  defined inside a function scope, they can only be accessed by that one function they were defined in.

Member variables are variables that are associated with a specific object of a class, they can only be declared inside a class's scope.

All member variables are global variables, but not all global variables are member variables.

*Field* is another term to describe *variable*. Similar to how *method* is another term to describe *function*, [i.e. they mean the same thing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html), at least in Java :)

```
const int a = 0 // global variable, can be accessed from anywhere in the program

class Example {
    int b; // member variable, also a global variable, can only be accessed inside this class

int fun () {
  Foo c; // local variable, can only be accessed inside this method

  return 0;
   }
}
```